# How to stop Sublime Text 3 from wrapping lines in curly braces

Tags: curly-braces, sublimetext3

I'm working with a Handlebars (.hbs) file that looks something like this:

```
<div>
  ...

  _
  <button {{action "signin"}}>Sign in</button>
</div>
```

When I place the cursor at the underscore position and enter a curly brace {. It wraps the entire `<button>` line in braces:

```
{
<button {{action "signin"}}>Sign in</button>
}
```

But what I want is just:

```
{}
<button ...
```

[ and ( don't have this behavior. Is there any way to disable this feature of Sublime Text? I took a look through the keybindings but couldn't find the differences between square brackets and curly braces that make them act differently.

Answer (score 1):

My solution relies on you having a syntax applied, so may or may not work out of the box.

Try adding the following into your user key bindings.

```
{ "keys": ["{"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "{${0:$SELECTION}}"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "indented_block", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.handlebar", "match_all": true },
    ]
}
```

I guessed a scope for handlebar, so change it if you need to. If you do not have a syntax definition associated with the file type, comment and I'll update my answer.

For future reference, I found the command being run by doing "sublime.log_commands(True)" in the console. From there I found the related key binding and created a way to override for a specific type of file.

Comment: I tried your solution to no avail. However I also enabled the console and noticed that the { key is triggering the "wrap_block" command.Now I'm attempting to duplicate the "insert_snippet" behavior in a "wrap_block" overwrite. Otherwise I'm not sure how to remove the wrap_block command from the default prefs.

Comment: Ah ha! I had to overwrite all the "{" commands and omit the "wrap_block" command from my user keymap file.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. The context I have there is a result of the wrap_block command you found. I simply added the selector context and replaced the command with insert snippet. I'm guessing a scoping issue was preventing it from working. My solution would keep that behavior in other file types. Of course, I should have mentioned if you didn't want that behavior at all, you could simply remove the selector context.

Comment: By replacing the command with "insert_snippet" wouldn't that leave the default "wrap_block" free to continue to act? I'm not actually sure why my solution worked, it seems like it should still act with the old behavior.

Comment: Yes it would still act under certain conditions. I am (and you are too) taking advantage of how ST searches for the command to run. It starts with the User directory, then any installed packages, and finally the Default directory. If there is a context that matches, it runs that command and stops searching. So, for your case, a context matches in the User directory, so it runs that. It never falls through to the default directory, where the wrap_block command would be run. I hope that makes things a little more clear for you.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue in Sublime Text 3 in JSX files. After reading the comments under skuroda's answer, I was able to fix it by duplicating/overriding the key & context of the "wrap_block" binding but subbing in the command and args from the "insert_snippet" binding.

That looks like this (add to the list of User key bindings):

```
    { "keys": ["{"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "{$0}"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "indented_block", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$", "match_all": true },
        ]
    },
```